# Cucumber: How to get a list of tags in an After block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I've got the following in a feature support file:

```
After do |scenario|
  screen_shot_and_save_page if scenario.failed?
end
```

I'd like to run this *only* if the scenario tags included `@javascript`. How can I write that?

Answer (score 4):

```
After("@sometag") do |scenario|
  screen_shot_and_save_page if scenario.failed?
end
```

You can also `or`, `and` and `not` the tags. For instance

```
After("@alpha,~@bravo","@charlie") do |scenario|
  screen_shot_and_save_page if scenario.failed?
end
```

The above will only be applied to scenarios that have the `@charlie` tag and either the `@alpha` tag or don't have the `@bravo` tag